# How to recursively set permissions on a Mac for network transfer?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion

I have files on one Mac I am trying to transfer to another via firewire (both Lion, for the record). I have the source Mac set as a network drive. Numerous files on that Mac, however, do not have the read-permission set for 'everyone'. I have tried using `chmod -v -R +r` to no avail. Without the permission set, copying of the particular files fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you try?  Can you copy the commands and output from Terminal to a comment here so I can see them?  Also, can you show the output of a "mount" command?

Comment: The output of `chmod ...` is nothing now. Before it was listing the names of the few files having permissions changed. As far as the output of the `mount` command goes, I am not sure where I would find that information since the mounting was done by simply clicking in the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a "get info" on the source drive (or folder on the source drive) that you're trying to access.  You can "get info" either by right (control) clicking on the drive or folder icon, or selecting the icon and pressing cmd-I or choosing File->Get Info from the pulldown menu

In the get info box, click the little padlock in the lower right corner if it's locked and enter the administrator password.

At the bottom of the Get Info box, set the privileges you need in the "Sharing & Permissions" box at the bottom.

Then (and this is the magic part), click on the little gear at the bottom of the Get Info window and choose "Apply to enclosed items"  That will make the change propagate down into all the subfolders of the disk/folder you did the Get Info on.

These instructions are for Snow Leopard, but hopefully will be similar on Lion.

Hope it helps.